# MySql Query to get certain number of values from limit and order by rand()

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

In below SQL query I need  25 rows containing product = 'y' and 25 rows having product = 'n'.  **Product** is a column having Y/N value only. In limit of random 50 rows I need 25 rows from each values.

```
SELECT qno 
FROM `wp_question_bank` 
where brand='XYZ' 
and department='DOMESTIC' 
and product = 'y' 
and priority = 'p1' 
ORDER BY RAND() limit 50
```

Kindly assist. I have tried Union but it didn't work.

Comment: Hint: `UNION` for each subset.

Comment: Why not running 2 queries or 1 `UNION`?

Comment: Can you share sample input data, and the expected output for that, such that others can try to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `UNION` for each product type:

```
(SELECT qno
FROM `wp_question_bank`
WHERE brand='XYZ' AND department='DOMESTIC' AND product = 'y' AND priority = 'p1'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 25)

UNION ALL

(SELECT qno
FROM `wp_question_bank`
WHERE brand='XYZ' AND department='DOMESTIC' AND product = 'n' AND priority = 'p1'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 25)
```

Comment: It is showing error "#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY". Perhaps multiple order by and LIMIT can not be Union.

Comment: Use parentheses, Luke!

Comment: Thanks @PaulSpiegel, I simply forgot them. Updated.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @mitkosoft , it worked like charm. Thanks to PaulSpiegel for help. Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `row_number()` if you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
select qno
from (
    select qno, row_number() over(partition by product order by rand()) rn
    from wp_question_bank
    where brand='XYZ' and department='DOMESTIC' and priority = 'p1'
) t
where rn <= 25
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough rows of each type, you can do this without a subquery:

```
SELECT qno
FROM `wp_question_bank`
WHERE brand = 'XYZ' AND department = 'DOMESTIC' AND
      product IN ('n', 'y') AND priority = 'p1'
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY rand())
LIMIT 50;
```